# Is libcurl thread safe when built with GnuTLS

Tags: c, curl, libcurl, gnutls

One of the requirement for libcurl to be thread safe is that the underlying SSL library should be thread safe.

According to documentation of GnuTLS, it is thread safe by design.

> The GnuTLS library is thread safe by design, meaning that objects of the library such as TLS sessions, can be safely divided across threads as long as a single thread accesses a single object. This is sufficient to support a server which handles several sessions per thread. Read-only access to objects, for example the credentials holding structures, is also thread-safe.

However there are few use cases that needs to be taken care.

> A gnutls_session_t object could also be shared by two threads, one sending, the other receiving. However, care must be taken on the following use cases:

- > The re-handshake process in TLS 1.2 or earlier must be handled only  in a single thread and no other thread may be performing any operation.
- > The flag GNUTLS_AUTO_REAUTH cannot be used safely in this mode of operation.
- > Any other operation which may send or receive data, like key update (c.f., gnutls_session_key_update), must not be performed while threads are receiving or writing.
- > The termination of a session should be handled, either by a single thread being active, or by the sender thread using gnutls_bye with GNUTLS_SHUT_WR and the receiving thread waiting for a return value of zero (or timeout on certain servers which do not respond).
- > The functions gnutls_transport_set_errno and gnutls_record_get_direction should not be relied during parallel operation.

Does libcurl take care of above use cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does.

libcurl does not use gnutls_session_t objects from multiple threads, so those mentioned precautions don't apply (nor does it do any of the other things said to not be thread-safe). Threaded libcurl use with GnuTLS (or other TLS backends) should be fine as long as you follow [libcurl's thread-safety guidelines](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html).

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Stenberg.